# Flink example job of long-running streaming processing

Tags: apache-flink

I'm looking for a Flink example job of long-running streaming processing for test purposes. I checked the streaming/WordCount included in the Flink project, but seems it is not long-running, after processing the input file, it exits.

Do I need to write one by myself? What is the simplest way to get an endless stream input?

Comment: I ended up with creating a TCP server as socketTextStream source by myself https://github.com/functicons/go-examples/tree/master/textstream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WordCount example exits because its source is finite. Once it has fully processed its input, it exits.

The [Flink Operations Playground](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/getting-started/docker-playgrounds/flink-operations-playground.html) is a nice example of a streaming job that runs forever.

Comment: Ah you are right @David Anderson. Did my mind tricked me or did it used a FileSource in the past?

Answer (score 1):

Per definition every streaming job runs "forever" as long as you don't define any halt criterias or cancel the job manually. I guess you are asking for some job which consumes from some kind of infinite source. The most simplest job I could find was the twitter example which is included at the flink-project itself:

https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/streaming/scala/examples/twitter/TwitterExample.scala

With some tweaking you could also use the socket-example (there you have some more control of the source):

https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/streaming/scala/examples/socket/SocketWindowWordCount.scala

Hope I got your question right and this helps.

Comment: Yes, I just want to find a job which runs forever. Do you know why the WordCount example exits? What is the "halt criterias" for it?